# How to store string value in persistent store blackberry

Tags: blackberry, persistent-storage

How do I utilize Blackberry's persistent store in order to store a string?

Like:

```
String str = "5";
```

Comment: Based on your comments below: Why are you storing an integer value (media player volume) as a String? You'd be better off storing it as an int. Also, try to avoid posting large amounts of code in comments, far better to update your question with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static PersistentObject persistentObject;`
public static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc6d6daL;
public static Hashtable persistentHashtable;
```

***"username" is the field for identifying the value.***

The following code will retrive the stored email address.

```
persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);
if (persistentObject.getContents() == null) {
        persistentHashtable = new Hashtable();
        persistentObject.setContents(persistentHashtable);
    } else {
        persistentHashtable = (Hashtable) persistentObject.getContents();
    }

    if (persistentHashtable.containsKey("username")
            ) {

        String temp= persistentHashtable.get("username"));
    }
```

***For inserting values to Persistant store, Use the following code:***

```
persistentHashtable.put("username", str);
```

Comment: what you mean by something else ?

Comment: `class MyClass {
 public static Vector vol; 
public static PersistentObject store; 

public MyClass

{
Some code
Get();
}

I want to store this string "50"
This is the value for media player volume.When player start, get value from str and convert to int.
String str = "50";
int _currentVolume = Integer.parseInt(str);

}`

Hi and thank you for reply. But i need some other to save String.

I have this code:



How to store this String "50" to persistant volume? I know... i'm newbie :)

Comment: you want to store the string value in vector vol ?

Comment: Yes master :) I try many options but i'm novice and all my try to store volume not working...:( I made simple player. When application start, default value is 50, when click play and chcange volume to 40 and exit application, and turn on again program volume is 50(default).I have String str ="50" for volume and player get this volume from int _currentVolume = Integer.parseInt(str); But i donh have idea how to store this String str = "50"; in persistent store.

Comment: I onlu need store this value String str ="50"; in persistent store. Nothing more.Because player get this value and transform to int.